# How to render module view files of laravel 4

Tags: php, templates, laravel, laravel-4, file-not-found

I have a laravel 4.1 project with modular system. Here is the tree scheme.

```
app/
app/modules
app/modules/modulename/
app/modules/modulename/controllers/
app/modules/modulename/controllers/modulecontrollerfile.php
app/modules/modulename/views/
app/modules/modulename/views/moduleviewfile.php
```

I am trying to render view files in module controllers as follows:

```
View::addNamespace('moduleFoldername', '/app/modules/modulename/views');

return View::make('moduleFoldername::moduleviewfile');
```

Then I get the following error:

```
 InvalidArgumentException

 View [moduleviewfile] not found.
```

Which path is wrong in the code?

Comment: Your code is correct, the namespace should work! Can you post the part of your controller where you define this namespace?

Comment: for me work well View::make("modulename::viewname"), if view in some directory under views View::make("modulename::directory_name.viwename")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that one

```
View::addNamespace('package', app_path().'/modules/modulename/views');
```